# Just one of Entity Framework tables is not updated in EDMX file

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, edmx, entity-model

I am using VS 2012 and I face a strange problem.

When I delete all tables in the `.edmx` file and then update model from database and add all of tables back, one of my tables is not updated!

I was working on my project perfectly. I faced the problem when I made some changes in the database. However I always made changes in my database and before last time, everything was OK!

What is reason and solution?

Comment: It is not added or not updated?

Comment: If you already deleted all the tables from your `.edmx` - try to just delete the whole `.edmx` and start over - create a new Entity Data Model - does that work?

Comment: @giorgi-nakeuri:  not added! I deleted all tables and add all tables(when updating model) . but one of table not added! Then if i try to update model without deleting all tables, just that one table exist in list to Add! If i add that table, and update the model, problem still exists and that table never add!

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited, it may happen if you don't have primary key defined on the table. Check that.

Comment: Is there anything special about the name of the table (or one of its columns)? E.g. is there a space or a special character (exclamation mark, question mark etc.) in the table or one of its column names? Is the table name all digits, by any chance??

Comment: @marc_s : even if i delete the edmx file, not added.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri : Great! after last of changes, I removed primary key of that table! now i add PK and problem solved! You can write answer to my question.

Comment: @marc_s : many thanks. No. There was no special character in names.Problem found in PK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably the problem is that table in database have no primary key defined. Just create the one and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks.Problem solved! But why VS not display any error and notification about updating tables that have not PK?

Comment: @MohsenUnlimited, are you sure? I am getting those warnings, like table or view doesnt have pk or something like that. I can not check right now. Try opening edmx in text, xml editor and search for errors. I don't remember exactly where thise errors added. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d9c6ae8-80ff-42e8-ae12-c16d1fd896c3/adding-table-with-no-primary-key-to-entity-model-and-implementing-crud-operations?forum=adodotnetentityframework